# Updating an Sharepoint 2013 app (sharepoint hosted)

Tags: 2013, app, sharepoint-hosted-app, client-object-model

I have developed an app and I'm trying to get my head round what happens in the update process.

My app contains several lists some of which the user can update. If they then update their app with my newest version will their data be retained in the lists?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow an upgrade process to update the apps. That way data in the lists will be retained.

> For an update, you use the same product ID in the app manifest that
>   you used for the original version. The version number in the app
>   manifest should be greater than the version number of the original app
>   or the most recent update.

Following article at msdn describes it in detail:

[App for SharePoint update process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179904.aspx)

Comment: I had seen that article already but it does not seem to cover Sharepoint hosted JSOM apps...

Comment: Even though I haven't gone through it in detail, I think the process should be same for all types of apps.